# Bash 4.3+ - Recursive fibonacci

Tags: bash, recursion, fibonacci, bash4

I am working on my programming language which compiles into bash 4.3+ code. I am in the final stages of my language, but I have a small issue with recursion functions. Here's the bash code which is supposed to return the fibnacci number given an index.

```
#!/bin/bash

function fib() {
    local a=$1
    declare -n ret=$2
    if (( $a <= 2 )); then
        ret=1
        return
    fi
    fib $((a-1)) fib1
    fib $((a-2)) fib2

    ret=$((fib1+fib2))
    echo "fib($((a-1))) + fib($((a-2))) = $ret"
    return
}

num=5
fib $num result
echo 
echo "fib($num) = $result"
```

The problem in this code is that the fib(5) is giving 3 which is clearly wrong. What I think the problem is, when I pass fib1 and fib2 as a way to store the return value, they get overwritten by each call which assigns them. If that was the problem, how can I make `fib1` and `fib2` local to their execution scope.

Please note that I do not want to use a `return` statement to return the values, I want to try finding a solution using `declare -n` namerefs.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I think the problem is, when I pass fib1 and fib2 as a way to store the return value, they get overwritten by each call which assigns them.

Yep, and you can see that by printing the value of `fib1` between and after the recursive calls:

```
fib $((a-1)) fib1
echo "fib($a): fib1: $fib1"
fib $((a-2)) fib2
echo "fib($a): fib1: $fib1 fib2: $fib2"
```

You should see the value of `fib1` change during the second call. That's to be expected, since it wasn't declared `local` and there only is one global copy of `fib1`.

If you make them local... it doesn't help much.

Assume you start by calling `fib 4 result`. The first iteration will make `fib1` local, and call `fib 3 fib1`. Now the second iteration will also make `fib1` local, but it will also try to assign its return value to a variable of the same name. Since the access is by name, it saves the return value to its *own* copy of `fib1`.

This can be seen with a somewhat simpler script too, this tries to return a fixed value up from the bottom of the recursion:

```
#!/bin/bash  
foo() {         
    declare -n ret=$2
    if (( $1 == 0 )); then
        echo "foo($1) returning"
        ret=end          # this is the value that should bubble up
        return
    fi
    local x=initial$1    # use $1 here to track the level the value came from
    foo $(($1 - 1)) x
    ret=$x
    echo "foo($1) = $x"
    return
}
foo 3 result
echo "main:    $result"
```

The workaround I can think of is to have a separate global variable for the return value, and to immediately copy it to a local variable:

```
local fib1 fib2
fib $((a-1)) retval
fib1=$retval
fib $((a-2)) retval
fib2=$retval
```